# Animate View Off-Screen To The Right and Back In From the Left

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to replicate an animation found on the Apple App Store seen here. The app icons move from left to right continuously like a carousel and I'm trying to produce the same behaviour for a single UIView. Is anyone able to help with this? Really struggling: [image: app store]

Something I tried but it stops and repeats the animation without continuing from left to right.

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
        viewOfImageViews.center.x += container.bounds.width +

    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can archive this effect:

- Add a collection view
- Set cell width the same width as your superview
- Set your collection view scroll direction to horizontal
- Now in the code when the collection is loaded you scroll to the first section

  ```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1), at: .left, animated: true)
  }
  ```
- Now you can add this code below so when animation is done it updates the cells and scroll again

  ```
  func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      colors.append(colors.removeFirst())
      collView.reloadData()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.collView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .left, animated: false)
          self.collView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1), at: .left, animated: true)
      }
  }
  ```
- Change colors array to your array name which contains the images

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Any idea how?